# PHP mysqli_query - INSERT INTO not working, error unclear

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a lot of variables that I'm adding into a database from all the product pages on my website. Here is my PHP code:

```
$args = (array(
    "post_type" => "page",
    "meta_key" => "_wp_page_template",
    "meta_value" => "products.php",
    "posts_per_page" => 50
));

$queryPages = get_posts($args);

$con= mysqli_connect("localhost","pmdot","password","pmd_ot");
foreach($queryPages as $qp) {
    $qpID = $qp->ID;
    $name = get_post_meta($qpID, "pmd_name", true);
    $code = get_post_meta($qpID, "pmd_sku", true);
    $installation = get_post_meta($qpID, "pmd_installation", true);
    $age = get_post_meta($qpID, "pmd_agefrom", true);
    $length = get_post_meta($qpID, "pmd_length", true);
    $width = get_post_meta($qpID, "pmd_width", true);
    $height = get_post_meta($qpID, "pmd_height", true);
    $areal = get_post_meta($qpID, "pmd_areal", true);
    $areaw = get_post_meta($qpID, "pmd_areaw", true);
    $cfh = get_post_meta($qpID, "pmd_cfh", true);
    $weight = get_post_meta($qpID, "pmd_weight", true);
    $type[] = get_post_meta($qpID, "pmd_playtype", true);
    $accred[] = get_post_meta($qpID, "pmd_accreditation", true);
    $descr = get_post_meta($qpID, "pmd_shortdesc", true);
    $price = get_post_meta($qpID, "pmd_price", true);

    mysqli_query($con, 'INSERT INTO pmd_productdata (Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Code, Product_Installation, Age_Range, Product_Length, Product_Width, Product_Height, Minimum_Area_L, Minimum_Area_W, C_F_H, Product_Weight, Play_Type, Accreditations, Product_Desc, Product_Price) 
                        VALUES ($qpID, $name, $code, $installation, $age, $length, $width, $height, $areal, $areaw, $cfh, $weight, "placeholder", "placeholder", $descr, $price') or die ('Error:' .mysqli_error($con));
}
```

What this is doing is getting all the posts with the template `products.php` and then using all the custom fields to populate an SQL table with a query.

**NOTE: The arrays that you can see are not currently being used in the query as I thought that was the issue. Bonus points if someone can help me get all the values in that array to display in the respective field.**

**All of the columns in my table have varchar(255) as their char base, just in case some are not INTs when they should be.**

For some reason, I'm getting this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Now, as you can see the error is rather unclear, if anyone can shine some light on the situation I'd be very grateful.

My question is: Why am I getting that error, and what does it mean?

### EDIT [Resolved]

Now I'm getting a new error that I've fixed the VALUES () issue:

```
Unknown column '$qpID' in 'field list'
```

Is this because I need to separate the variables from the query: e.g.:

```
'VALUES (' . $qpID . ', ' . $name . ')' etc.;
```

### EDIT 2

The errors have now been fixed and the data is in the SQL Database, all I need now is to figure out how to get the 2 arrays to print all their values into the respective column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated query

```
mysqli_query($con, 'INSERT INTO pmd_productdata (Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Code, Product_Installation, Age_Range, Product_Length, Product_Width, Product_Height, Minimum_Area_L, Minimum_Area_W, C_F_H, Product_Weight, Play_Type, Accreditations, Product_Desc, Product_Price) 
                        VALUES ("'.$qpID.'", "'.$name.'", "'.$code.'", "'.$installation.'", "'.$age.'", "'.$length.'", "'.$width.'", "'.$height.'", "'.$areal.'", "'.$areaw.'", "'.$cfh.'", "'.$weight.'", "placeholder", "placeholder", "'.$descr.'", "'.$price.'")') or die ('Error:' .mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks very much! Errors are fixed and it's in the SQL database now.

Comment: Thanks for compliment.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `(` missing:

```
$price')
```

should:

```
$price)')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I really should've spotted that. The current error has been fixed with this suggestion, but now I'm getting a new one (Updated Question)

Comment: @Mallander I am not very good in php but I think you should use double quotes around the query string not a single quote

Comment: I usually would do, but before I had some items in the VALUES() that had `""` surround them so I just changed the two to singles instead of all the rest :P

Comment: @Mallander There you have to use singel quotes!

Comment: I've just been through and changed it, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

If you use wordpress you do not need to create a new connection.
This you can help you:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query('INSERT INTO pmd_productdata (Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Code, Product_Installation, Age_Range, Product_Length, Product_Width, Product_Height, Minimum_Area_L, Minimum_Area_W, C_F_H, Product_Weight, Play_Type, Accreditations, Product_Desc, Product_Price) 
                        VALUES ('".$qpID."', '".$name."', '".$code."', '".$installation."', '".$age."', '".$length."', '".$width."', '".$height."', '".$areal."', '".$areaw."', '".$cfh."', '".$weight."', "placeholder", "placeholder", '".$descr."', '".$price."')');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqli_query($con, 'INSERT INTO pmd_productdata (Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Code, Product_Installation, Age_Range, Product_Length, Product_Width, Product_Height, Minimum_Area_L, Minimum_Area_W, C_F_H, Product_Weight, Play_Type, Accreditations, Product_Desc, Product_Price) 
                        VALUES ($qpID, $name, $code, $installation, $age, $length, $width, $height, $areal, $areaw, $cfh, $weight, "placeholder", "placeholder", $descr, $price)') or die ('Error:' .mysqli_error($con));
```

unclosed VALUES()

Answer (score 1):

Try to put value variable in single quotes like `'$qpID','$name'` etc and whole query put in double quote.